# vb.net mutiple tables in dataset relations

Tags: vb.net

Don't know if this is even possible, but...
I have 3 tables:
CustomerTable
OrderHeaderTable
OrderDetailTable

The relationships are CustomerTable.CustomerNumber to OrderHeaderTable.CustomerNumber,
OrderHeaderTable.OrderNumber to OrderDetail.OrderNumber.

I am using DevExpress XtraGrid to display the information, using SQL stored procedure to capture data.

**I want/need to be able to form relation between OrderHeader and OrderDetail to display in grid but am unsure of how to make this work within code I have used thus far.**

Here is the VB code:

```
    Dim bsOrders As New BindingSource
    Dim dsDataSetOrders As New DataSet
    Dim daDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter

    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("spViewOrders", GetOpenConnection) With {.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure}
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add(New SqlParameter("@Action", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = 44
            .Add(New SqlParameter("@Exists", SqlDbType.Int)).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput
        End With

        daDataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
        daDataAdapter.Fill(dsDataSetOrders, "Orders")
        dsDataSetOrders.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("OrderHeader", dsDataSetOrders.Tables(0).Columns("Customer #"), _
                                                       dsDataSetOrders.Tables(1).Columns("Customer #")))

        bsOrders.DataSource = dsDataSetOrders
        bsOrders.DataMember = "Orders"
    End Using


    GridControl1.DataSource = bsOrders
    GridView1.BestFitColumns()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does spViewOrders pull the data you want from OrderHeader and OrderDetail? If so, you just need to add another Relations. If not, pull your desired data into a DataTable, add it to dsDataSetOrders.Tables and then add to the Relations.

Comment: spViewOrders pulls CustomerTable, OrderHeader, and OrderDetail.  Right now I have modified the sp to only pull Customer and Header tables since I could not get the Detail to work.

Comment: Am unsure of syntax to add another relation.  Please remember Customer and Header are linked by CustomerNumber, while Header and Detail are linked by OrderNumber.  If you could point out the syntax to add the detail relation I would appreciate.

Comment: dsDataSetOrders.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("DetailHeader", dsDataSetOrders.Tables(x).Columns("OrderNumber"), _
                                                       dsDataSetOrders.Tables(y).Columns("OrderNumber))) where x and y are the two tables you need to relate